# Find total number of leaves of a tree LISP

Tags: tree, scheme, lisp, racket

The following is a procedure that returns the total number of leaves of a tree.
for example (count-leaves '((1 2) () (3) (4 5 6))) returns 6
this is code so far i found is there any other way to achieve same thing?

```
(define (count-leaves t)
  (cond
    ((null? t)
      0)
    ((not (pair? t))
      1)
    (else
      (+ (count-leaves (car t))
         (count-leaves (cdr t))))))

; The general logic of this function is:
; If the tree is null, return 0
; elif: return 1 if at a leaf. We know
; That we're at a leaf if the position is not null and not a pair
; else: we are at a pair and must branch our function
; Testing it below:
1 ]=> (load "hierarchical_structures_1.scm")
;Loading "hierarchical_structures_1.scm"... done
;Value: count-leaves
1 ]=> (define tree-1 (cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
;Value: tree-1
1 ]=> tree-1
;Value 11: ((1 2) 3 4)
1 ]=> (count-leaves tree-1)
;Value: 4
```

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but it is inherently a recursive process so it isn't much to save from doing it differently. You should fix your indentation as it is impossible to read the code how it is formatted in your question. Eg. It seems like `((not (pair? t)) 1)` is outside the cond base don its placement right below.

Comment: you could traverse the tree, `cons`ing the leafs onto a flat list, then compute the `length` of the flattened list. it's _another_ way but not _better_ in any way.

Comment: you could write a `tree->stream` function lazily that produces individual leaf values and send the stream to a `element-counter` consumer. again it's _another_ way but not necessarily better.

Comment: you could write a generic `tree-fold` higher-order function that folds each node with an accumulator....

Comment: Does `(length (flatten tree))` count? It is not as efficient as your solution though.

Comment: Just a general comment: try and avoid using `t` as a variable in Lisp, as it could be confused with the value `T` (not a problem in Scheme, but in Common Lisp this would probably not work).